# Color area under curve with Lattice

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I would like to color/shade the area between two intervals under a normal curve, such the one produced in the example. An interval could be 125:140 or the segment beyond 140.

```
library(lattice)

e4a <- seq(60, 170, length = 10000)
e4b <- dnorm(e4a, 110, 15)
xyplot(e4b ~ e4a,
   type = "l",
   scales = list(x = list(at = seq(60, 170, 5)), rot = 45),
   panel = function(x, ...){
           panel.xyplot(x, ...)
           panel.abline( v = c(110, 125, 95, 140, 80, 95), lty = 2)
   })
```

[image]

I found a really straightforward solution for the [R graphic base system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987909/shaded-area-under-curve-r), but I did not find an equivalent solution for Lattice.

Comment: @Hack-R That's base graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`panel.polygon` exists:

```
xyplot(e4b ~ e4a,
       type = "l",
       scales = list(x = list(at = seq(60, 170, 5)), rot = 45),
       panel = function(x,y, ...){
           panel.xyplot(x,y, ...)
           panel.abline( v = c(110, 125, 95, 140, 80, 95), lty = 2)

           xx <- c(125, x[x>=125 & x<=140], 140) 
           yy <- c(0,   y[x>=125 & x<=140], 0) 
           panel.polygon(xx,yy, ..., col='red')
       })
```

A bit messy with getting the polygon correct.

Note that `e4a` is sorted in your data.  If that were not so, you would likely need to sort them prior to presenting to `panel.polygon`.

[image]